# Composition of functions on Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface, $p\in X$, $U$ a neighbourood of $p$, $f:U\setminus\{p\}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a olomorphic function on the punctured set. How can I prove that $f$ has a removable singularity/pole/essential singularity in $p$ if and only if, for every chart $\phi:W\to V \subset \mathbb{C}$, with $p \in W$, $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ has a removable singularity/pole/essential singularity?
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to prove, it is the definition, and the point is that you can replace "for every chart" by "for one chart"

Comment: Ok, and how do I prove the fact that the statement is true for every chart is equivalent to the fact that it is true for one chart?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic in one chart at $p$ then it is analytic in every chart at $p$, meromorphic = quotient of analytic functions, essential singularity = isolated singularity and not meromorphic